# Smooth edges of non-rectangular form in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, drawing, smoothing

I've created a form with rounded corners using Form.Region. It works, but unfortunately the rounding appears rough. Are there any tricks for smoothing such shaped form corners? I know many applications support this, just not sure how to make it in .NET.

Thanks guys.

Comment: The technique you are looking for is commonly known as Anti-Aliasing.

Comment: @enriquein https://web.archive.org/web/20120620223040/http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=288178

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no good fix for this, regions cannot be anti-aliased.  This is inevitable, anti-aliasing only works when you know the background colors so you can blend properly.  That's not an option for windows, the background is by design unpredictable.  If this is a splash screen then you can fake it by taking a screen shot of the background and drawing your fake window on top of it.  Won't work for more than a few seconds.

Best thing to do is to keep the corner radius small so it is not so noticeable.  Also use a tool like SysInternals' ZoomIt and take a close look at the rounded corners of a program like Windows Media Player.  Note the gray tones it uses to draw the border.

Answer (score 8):

From what I've read online most people end up overriding the forms onpaint event and drawing the region there.  This allows them to use GDI+ with antialiasing and make it look much cleaner.

The examples I found:

http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=283&artID=7833
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=288178

Comment: second link dead