# VB Transparent Splash Screen Solution Leaves "Outline" on Objects

Tags: vb.net, transparency, splash-screen

I tried the following solution in order to make a transparent splash screen- [How to design a cool semi transparent splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979232/how-to-design-a-cool-semi-transparent-splash-screen)

However, with that solution the background color I use still kind of outlines my frame label and background image. Is there a way around this? I'm already using a .png image for my background image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smooth edges of non-rectangular form in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727726/smooth-edges-of-non-rectangular-form-in-net)

Comment: You probably have an image that uses partially transparent pixels, Photoshop likes to make those.  They destroy the color-keying effect by altering the color of the background.  Shows up as a fringe around objects in the image.  You need per-pixel alpha transparency instead.  Not directly supported in Winforms, you can use pinvoke to get it.  Just google "windows forms per-pixel alpha transparency" to find the code.